# How to control item's View of ListView by GestureDetector?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gesture

I set a `onTouchListener` to `ListView`, I want to control the item's view of my ListView, but I found methods in `SimpleOnGestureListener`,there are no View parameter to given, so how can I control item of ListView?

add:
a XML for layout of item,I use the `FrameLayout`, the item just show a `TextView`, and a cover `ImageView` with ALPHA 0.5 is `gone`, I want to horizontal scroll one item then set the cover's visibility is `VISIBLE`.

Comment: What do you want to control in there?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: I add more content on my question~@gunar @Biraj Zalavadia